# File upload to the server directory

Tags: java, file-upload, struts

I am uploading an excel file to the tomcat server. Which is saving inside my eclipse directory `D:\workspace_Eclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\StatusPortal\Job_doc\abc.xls`

When ever i am accessing this file its giving me file not found Exception `\Job_doc\abc.xls`.
 Its could not able to find the path which is i am giving while accessing the file like 
      `\Job_doc\abc.xls`

I am giving the path  `\Job_doc\abc.xls`  while accessing.

Comment: Try getting the absolute path of "\Job_doc\abc.xls" while accessing.

Comment: You know the actual path is `D:\workspace_Eclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\StatusPortal\Job_doc\abc.xls`.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading your file using `ClassLoader` as below:

```
   InputStream inputStream = 
          getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/Job_doc/abc.xls");
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream ));
```

If you want to get the `File` object, then try as below:

```
  URI uri = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/Job_doc/abc.xls").toURI();
  File file = new File(uri);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using a relative path. Eclipse will use the current working directory to be a temp location for deploying the webapp. So the file is uploaded to the folder relative  to this path (This happens when you start the app from eclipse `Run On Server`. Define your paths as static constants(May be you can use absolute paths for testing). After testing you can use the relative paths on production deployment.

Still, you can do alternate way. Dont use the integrated tomcat server of Eclipse. Use a standalone server, use the descriptor file to link the webapp in workspace to tomcat. After the save, just reload the app  in tomcat manager and try.